# How to change the border color of a text input in a react native app

Tags: react-native

How can i change the border color or how can add or change the style in a text input field in react native when the  text input field is focused. 
(for android)

Answer (score 36):

You can do use [`onFocus`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onfocus) and [`onBlur`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#onblur) to do the job

```
state: {
    isFocused: true
}

 handleFocus = () => this.setState({isFocused: true})

 handleBlur = () => this.setState({isFocused: false})

 <TextInput
         onFocus={this.handleFocus}
         onBlur={this.handleBlur}
         style={[//Your Styles, {
             borderBottomColor: this.state.isFocused
                 ? 'black'
                 : 'red',
             borderBottomWidth: 1,
         }]}
     />
```

Comment: it's works for single field. But when multiple field how it will work ?

Comment: For multiple fields you need to make this as a separate component and pass `isFocused` prop based on the parent component.

Answer (score 3):

Use the below code that helps to change the border color of react native application.

```
export default class HomeActivity extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>
          Remove TextInput Component Bottom Underline in React Native
        </Text>

        <TextInput
          style={{ height: 40, width: "95%", borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1,  marginBottom: 20 }}
          // Adding hint in TextInput using Placeholder option.
          placeholder="Enter Your First Name"
          // Making the Under line Transparent.
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        />

        <TextInput
          style={{ height: 40, width: "95%", borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 1,  marginBottom: 20 }}
          // Adding hint in TextInput using Placeholder option.
          placeholder="Enter Your First Name"
          // Making the Under line Transparent.
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        />

        <TextInput
          style={{ height: 40, width: "95%", borderColor: 'blue', borderWidth: 1,  marginBottom: 20 }}
          // Adding hint in TextInput using Placeholder option.
          placeholder="Enter Your First Name"
          // Making the Under line Transparent.
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Useful answer for having border on input control.

Comment: I have added `borderColor: "#000011",` already.`borderWidth: 1` helped me to show it on UI