# How to change the border color of textinputs when typing in React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I have a TextInput in react native like this:

```
<SafeAreaView style={ChatWindowStyles.bottomAreaViewStyles}>
  <TextInput
    className="userMessageInput"
    style={ChatWindowStyles.messageTextInputStyles}
    placeholder="Enter a message"
    onChangeText={(text) => userMessage = (text)}
                
  />
</SafeAreaView>
```

I want the border color to be blue when I am typing something in the TextInput. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the border color of a text input in a react native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168669/how-to-change-the-border-color-of-a-text-input-in-a-react-native-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, View, TextInput, Text } from 'react-native'


export default function Example() {

    const [value, setValue] = useState('')
    const [isTextInputFocused, setTextInputFocused] = useState(false)

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', }}>
                <TextInput
                    value={value}
                    onChangeText={value => setValue(value)}
                    style={{ height: 60, width: '90%', marginLeft: '5%', borderColor: isTextInputFocused == true ? 'blue' : 'black', borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 10, paddingLeft: 10 }}
                    placeholder='Enter text'
                    onFocus={() => setTextInputFocused(true)}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => setTextInputFocused(false)}
                    onEndEditing={() => setTextInputFocused(false)}
                />
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried this, but this shows some hook errors.

Comment: Please share a screen shot along with your code and try this example on snack expo above code is working 100 %
Here is expo link => https://snack.expo.dev/iTltbf82n