# React Native Input Focus Color

Tags: javascript, react-native, input

I created a custom wrapper for my Input and I changed the border color when it's focused. The issue is that the borderColor parameter seems to be different than the color of the border of the focused element (see img). Which style param am I supposed to change if not borderColor?

```
import { Input } from 'native-base';
```

[image]

Comment: Chekck this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50168669/how-to-change-the-border-color-of-a-text-input-in-a-react-native-app

Comment: That's what I'm doing and the result I get is the one in the image above. There is still a thin blue line and I feel like I want to change that one's color instead of creating a border atop.

Comment: Try this export const BaseTheme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Input: {
      baseStyle: {
        color: 'secondary.500',
        borderColor: 'secondary.500',
        _focus: {
          color: 'red.900',
          borderColor: 'red.900',
          height: '150px',
        },
      },
    },
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

work for me

```
 <TextInput
      selectionColor="#ff0000" // Replace with the color you want
      placeholder="Enter text here"
    />
```

Comment: Only works for TextInput and not for Input though ...